# Facing issue in AMQP Connector while deployng war file in tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, mule, amqp, mule-studio

I am getting error in AMQP Connector while deploying war file in mule tomcat.
In Anypoint studio its working fine, but while deployng in tomcat i am getting following error

```
org.mule.api.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Failed to invoke lifecycle phase "start" on object: AmqpConnector
{
  name=AMQP_0_9_Connector
  lifecycle=initialise
  this=3eb847dc
  numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers=4
  createMultipleTransactedReceivers=true
  connected=false
  supportedProtocols=[amqp]
  serviceOverrides=<none>
}

    at org.mule.lifecycle.phases.DefaultLifecyclePhase.applyLifecycle(DefaultLifecyclePhase.java:248)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleCallback.doApplyLifecycle(RegistryLifecycleCallback.java:91)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleCallback.onTransition(RegistryLifecycleCallback.java:67)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager.invokePhase(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:140)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager.fireLifecycle(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:111)
    at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistryBroker.fireLifecycle(AbstractRegistryBroker.java:88)
    at org.mule.registry.MuleRegistryHelper.fireLifecycle(MuleRegistryHelper.java:141)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager$MuleContextLifecycleCallback.onTransition(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:91)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager$MuleContextLifecycleCallback.onTransition(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:87)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager.invokePhase(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:69)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager.fireLifecycle(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:61)
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleContext.start(DefaultMuleContext.java:294)
    at org.mule.config.builders.MuleXmlBuilderContextListener.initialize(MuleXmlBuilderContextListener.java:96)
    at org.mule.config.builders.MuleXmlBuilderContextListener.contextInitialized(MuleXmlBuilderContextListener.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5099)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5615)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:899)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1092)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1984)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of org/apache/catalina/loader/WebappClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "org/apache/commons/logging/Log"
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:3175)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1372)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1860)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1734)
```

I am using mule 3.8.0 , my flow is as follow

```
 <amqp:connector name="AMQP_0_9_Connector" validateConnections="true" host="XXX.XX" username="XX" password="XX" doc:name="AMQP-0-9 Connector"/>
 <flow name="rabbitmq_mavenFlow">
        <servlet:inbound-endpoint path="/message" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="Servlet"/>
        <set-payload value="test message " doc:name="Set Payload"/>

        <amqp:outbound-endpoint  queueName="orders"  queueDurable="true" responseTimeout="10000" exchange-pattern="request-response" connector-ref="AMQP_0_9_Connector" doc:name="AMQP-0-9"/>
```

Please help me to solve it

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

@user3855589, you probably have two different versions of commons-logging: one in your war and one in tomcat. You should put the one in your war in provided scope (if you are using maven) or just exclude it from your war, and than deploy it in Tomcat. Check out a similar [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31212403/deployment-on-tomcat-constraint-violation-when-resolving-method-org-slf4j-impl).